# How to invoke my App and Launch it when some specific opens

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest, launcher

I want to track an app i.e "com.facebook.katana", i am already am having it's package name, now my question is that, i  to invoke my App and Launch it when that app("com.facebook.katana") opens, Ok, let's get straight, i am making an App locker but i just want to lock this app("com.facebook.katana") only! i'll do the else stuff but just need help in launching my activity when that app launches!
Thanks in advance!

I am using this code currently:

```
        ActivityManager mActivityManager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    List<ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo> RunningTask = mActivityManager.getRunningTasks(1);
    ActivityManager.RunningTaskInfo ar = RunningTask.get(0);

    String activityOnTop = ar.topActivity.getClassName ();
```

Comment: there are many opensource app lock code available

Comment: Those are very complex for me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TL;DR;*

You'll have to create a [Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) that periodically checks which is the foreground `Activity` and if it belongs to `com.facebook.katana` with the [ActivityManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager).

If so, start your locker `Activity`.

Your code is OK, just put it in the service I've described above.

Please note that if you are targeting Oreo+, you'll have to make it as a foreground service.

*LR*

So, in Android when you want to do a job periodically without having your app on top of the screen (which means your app is in background or not even started) you have multiple options, this is called [scheduling tasks](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/scheduling).

The option I'm giving you here is the `Service` one, for multiple reasons you could figure out reading the documentation I've linked each time.

In order to do so, create a Service like this:

```
class ForegroundScanService : Service() {

    val handler = Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? {
        return null
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int {  
        startForeground(1,  createNotification())
        checkApp()
        // Ended
        return START_STICKY
    }

    fun checkApp() {
        // Detect if the target app is on top, if yes invoke your app with an intent if it hasn't been done already
        if(appIsDetected()) {
            startYourApp()
        }
        // Ask the system to restart us, there are many ways to do this, each one will impact the battery in a different way
        handler.postDelayed(object: Runnable() {
            override fun run() {
                checkApp()
            }
        }, 5000);
    }

}
```

Then declare it in your Manifest and start it from your app activity.
As the Service will be alive and continuously running the "best" way is to use a ForegroundService. If you don't and choose to use WorkManager or AlarmManager or something else, it is better for the battery but limited in relaunch time.

Although the implementation is not the one you picked, this should explain the way it works.

By the way you can find documentation about [Handler here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler).

Comment: Hey are you on it? or not?

Comment: What do you mean by "more specific" ? Do you want me to copy/past a bunch of code that works ?

Comment: Sorry but i think miss understood my words, "More Specific"! but the reason was that actually to be fair, your answer is very short, which does not contain enough explanation, for a beginner, if i would capable of that, i wouldn't even ask the question!

Comment: Accepted your answer, brother!

Comment: Thanks :) Hope it helped you